# How to avoid context switching in Java ExecutorService

Tags: java, threadpool, anylogic

I use a software (AnyLogic) to export runnable jar files that themselves repeated re-run a set of simulations with different parameters (so-called parameter variation experiments). The simulations I'm running have very RAM intensive, so I have to limit the number of cores available to the jar file. In AnyLogic, the number of available cores is easily set, but from the Linux command line on the servers, the only way I know how to do this is by using the `taskset` command to just manually specify the available cores to use (using a CPU affinity "mask"). This has worked very well so far, but since you have to specify individual cores to use, I'm learning that there can be pretty substantial differences in performance depending on which cores you select. For example, you would want to maximize the use of CPU cache levels, so if you choose cores that share too much cache, you'll get much slower performance.

Since AnyLogic is written in Java, I can use Java code to specify the running of simulations. I'm looking at using the Java ExecutorService to build a pool of individual runs such that I can just specify the size of the pool to be whatever number of cores would match the RAM of the machine I'm using. I'm thinking that this would offer a number of benefits, most importantly perhaps the computer's scehduler can do a better job of selecting the cores to minimize runtime.

In my tests, I built a small AnyLogic model that take about 10 seconds to run (it just switches between 2 statechart states repeatedly). Then I created a custom experiment with this simple code.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Simulation experiment = new Simulation();
    experiment.variable = i;
    service.execute( () -> experiment.run() );
}
```

What I would hope to see is that only 2 `Simulation` objects start up at a time, since that's the size of the thread pool. But I see all 10 start up and running in parallel over the 2 threads. This makes me think that context switching is happening, which I assume is pretty inefficient.

When, instead of calling the AnyLogic `Simulation`, I just call a custom Java class (below) in the `service.execute` function, it seems to work fine, showing only 2 `Tasks` running at a time.

```
public class Task implements Runnable, Serializable {

    public void run() {
        traceln("Starting task on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        traceln("Ending task on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the AnyLogic function seems to be setting up all the simulations at once?

Comment: Are you sure `experiment.run()` is synchronous? Maybe it starts its own thread(s).

Comment: Great point. I'm a novice at concurrent programming. Now that you ask this, I think they do start their own process. Didn't think of that. Is there a way to lock that call into the same thread as the calling one or something?

Comment: Yes the `ExperimentSimulation` `run` function is asynchronous and launches threads. The 'normal' approach is to sleep and poll `getState` until it's `FINISHED` or `ERROR` as Hernan guessed. The `onAfterExperiment` is the API version of the equivalent action in a Simulation experiment's properties, and Hernan's semaphore-based approach using it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this whole question has been nullified by what I think is a relatively new addition to AnyLogic's functionality. You can specify an ini file with a specified number of "parallel workers".

https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Frunning%2Fexport-java-application.html&cp=0_3_9&anchor=customize-settings

But I had managed to find a workable solution just before finding this (better) option. Hernan's answer was *almost* enough. I think it was hampered by some vagaries of AnyLogic's engine (as I detailed in a comment).

The best version I could muster myself was using `ExecuterService`. In a Custom Experiment, I put this code:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    int t = i;
    tasks.add( () -> simulate(t) );
}

try{
    traceln("starting setting up service");
    List<Future<Integer>> futureResults = service.invokeAll(tasks);
    
    traceln("finished setting up service");
    
    List<Integer> res = futureResults.stream().parallel().map(
        f -> {
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("----- Future Results are ready -------");
    

    System.out.println("----- Finished -------");
    
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

service.shutdown();
```

The key here was using the Java `Future`. Also, to use the `invokeAll` function, I created a function in the Additional class code block:

```
public int simulate(int variable){
    // Create Engine, initialize random number generator:
    Engine engine = createEngine();
    // Set stop time
    engine.setStopTime( 100000 );
    // Create new root object:
    Main root = new Main( engine, null, null );
    root.parameter = variable;
    // Prepare Engine for simulation:
    engine.start( root );
    // Start simulation in fast mode:
    //traceln("attempting to acquire 1 permit on run "+variable);
    //s.acquireUninterruptibly(1);
    traceln("starting run "+variable);
    engine.runFast();
    traceln("ending run "+variable);
    //s.release();
    // Destroy the model:
    engine.stop();
    
    traceln( "Finished, run "+variable);
    return 1;
}
```

The only limitation I could see to this approach is that I don't have a waiting-while loop to output progress every few minutes. But instead of finding a solution to that, I must abandon this work for the much better settings file solution in the link up top.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `Simulation` extends from [ExperimentParamVariation](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FExperimentParamVariation.html). The key to achieve what you want would be to determine when the experiment has ended.

The documentation shows some interesting methods like [getProgress()](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FExperimentParamVariation.html&anchor=getProgress--) and [getState()](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FExperimentRunFast.html&anchor=getState--), but you would have to poll those methods until the progress is `1` or the state is `FINISHED` or `ERROR`. There are also the methods [onAfterExperiment()](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FExperimentMultipleRuns.html&anchor=onAfterExperiment--) and [onError()](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FExperiment.html&anchor=onError-java.lang.Throwable-) that should be called by the engine to indicate that the experiment has ended or there was an error. I think you could use these last two methods with a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to control how many experiments run at once:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentParamVariation;

public class Simulation extends ExperimentParamVariation</* Agent */> {

  private final Semaphore semaphore;

  public Simulation(Semaphore semaphore) {
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
  }

  public void onAfterExperiment() {
    this.semaphore.release();
    super.onAfterExperiment();
  }

  public void onError(Throwable error) {
    this.semaphore.release();
    super.onError(error);
  }

  // run() cannot be overriden because it is final
  // You could create another run method or acquire a permit from the semaphore elsewhere
  public void runWithSemaphore() throws InterruptedException {
    // This acquire() will block until a permit is available or the thread is interrupted
    this.semaphore.acquire();
    this.run();
  }
}
```

Then you will have to configure a semaphore with the desired number of permits an pass it to the `Simulation` instances:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

// ...

Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Simulation experiment = new Simulation(semaphore);

    // ...

    // Handle the InterruptedException thrown here
    experiment.runWithSemaphore();

    /* Alternative to runWithSemaphore(): acquire the permit and call run().
    semaphore.acquire();
    experiment.run();
    */
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very likely candidate. Thanks. I'll see if I can make a solution from this information and select this answer if I get it to work. As a note, the `Simulation` object is just a single simulation, so it inherits from `ExperimentSimulation`. But yes, I can get the progress over time within that.

Comment: To test, I tried a version just putting a `Semaphore` object (with 1 permit) within a `Parameter Variation Experiment` object. In "Before simulation run", I acquire 1 permit. In "after simulation run", I release it. If I expose only 1 core using AnyLogic's menu, it works fine. But if I let it have 2 cores, the model freezes at the end of a single simulation. It's almost like like it starts another simulation before finishing the first one, but it can't since there are not permits to acquire. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @buggaby, sorry, I do not have any experience with AnyLogic. I do not know what do you mean by "Before simulation run" or "after simulation run". I just proposed this option by looking at the javadocs.

Comment: You did a great job with that limited exposure to AnyLogic! Thanks! I'm sure I'll find a solution. I'll update this when I get it, but I think the `Semaphore` framework will do it for me.